# Java:Evaluation of Mathematical Expression only from left to right

Tags: java

I have written a Java program which evaluates a mathematical expression from left to right (no precedence, just left to right).  However, I'm not getting the desired output.

```
import java.util.*;      
public class Evaluation {              
    //private static final char[] validOperators = {'/','*','+','-'};      
    private Evaluation() 
    {
        /* Using a private contructor to prevent instantiation
           Using class as a simple static utility class
         */
    }

    private static int evaluate(String leftSide, char oper, String rightSide)
            throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        System.out.println("Evaluating: " + leftSide +  " (" + oper + ") " + rightSide);
        int total = 0;
        int leftResult = 0;
        int rightResult = 0;
        String originalString =leftSide;
        int operatorLoc  = findOperatorLocation(leftSide);
        leftSide = leftSide.substring(0,operatorLoc);
        rightSide = originalString.substring(operatorLoc+1,operatorLoc+2);
        String remainingString = originalString.substring(operatorLoc+2,originalString.length());

        System.out.println("leftSide -->"+leftSide);
        System.out.println("rightSide -->"+rightSide);
        System.out.println("remainingString --->"+remainingString);

        try {
            leftResult = Integer.parseInt(leftSide);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid value found in portion of equation: "
                + leftSide);
        }

        try {
            rightResult = Integer.parseInt(rightSide);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid value found in portion of equation: "
                + rightSide);
        }

        System.out.println("Getting result of: " + leftResult + " " + oper + " " + rightResult);
        switch(oper)
        {
        case '/':
            total = leftResult / rightResult; break;
        case '*':
            total = leftResult * rightResult; break;
        case '+':
            total = leftResult + rightResult; break;
        case '-':
            total = leftResult - rightResult; break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operator.");
        }

        System.out.println("Returning a result of: " + total);
        String totally = String.valueOf(total)+remainingString;
        return evaluate(totally,findCharacter(totally),remainingString);
    }

    private static int findOperatorLocation(String string) {
        int index = -1;         
        index = string.indexOf(string.substring(1,2));
        if(index >= 0) {
            return index;
        }
        return index;
    }

    private static char findCharacter(String string) {
        char c='\u0000';  
        int index = -1;         
        index = string.indexOf(string.substring(1,2));
        if(index >= 0){             
            c = string.charAt(index);
            return c;
        }                       
        return c;   
    }

    public static int processEquation(String equation)
        throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        return evaluate(equation,'+',"0");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //String usage = "Usage: java MathParser equation\nWhere equation is a series"
        // + " of integers separated by valid operators (+,-,/,*)";

        //if(args.length < 1 || args[0].length() == 0)
        // System.out.println(usage);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter the equation to be evaluated ");

        String equation = (String)input.next();
        int result = Evaluation.processEquation(equation);
        System.out.println("The result of your equation ("
            + equation + ") is: " + result);

        //catch(IllegalArgumentException iae)
        //{
        //  System.out.println(iae.getMessage() + "\n" + usage);
        //}
    }
}
```

Here is the input I'm trying to use, and what I expect:

> 3+5*2-5
>   =>8*2-5
>   =>16-5
>   =>Expected Output :11

But I'm getting this output:

> Enter the equation to be evaluated 3+5*2-5
>   Evaluating: 3+5*2-5 (+) 0
>   leftSide -->3
>   rightSide -->5
>   remainingString --->*2-5
>   Getting result of: 3 + 5
>   Returning a result of: 8
>   Evaluating: 8*2-5 (*) *2-5
>   leftSide -->8
>   rightSide -->2
>   remainingString --->-5
>   Getting result of: 8 * 2
>   Returning a result of: 16
>   Evaluating: 16-5 (6) -5
>   leftSide -->1
>   rightSide -->-
>   remainingString --->5
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid value found in portion of equation: -
>       at Evaluation.evaluate(Evaluation.java:49)
>       at Evaluation.evaluate(Evaluation.java:70)
>       at Evaluation.evaluate(Evaluation.java:70)
>       at Evaluation.processEquation(Evaluation.java:98)
>       at Evaluation.main(Evaluation.java:112)

I'm unable to make my program generic for any equation entered.
I appreciate any help you can provide.
Please note this is not a homework question.

Comment: The two digit number is messing with your parsing. It was working just fine until you got 16 as a result.

Comment: Marcelo,how do i proceed.how do i make it generic for any digit entered,i have been struggling to get this rite.

Comment: not yet solved..how do i make it generic

Comment: Are you new to just Java or Programming?

Comment: Both Marcelo.Please could you provide me with the fix

Comment: I would recommend Java tutorials on strings and regular expressions. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your findOperatorLoc is incorrect.

It automatically assumes that the operator is the second character.

```
index = string.indexOf(string.substring(1,2));
```

EDIT -- A cleaner implementation of this might be like so. split your equation based on operators and then based on operands. You will be left with 2 arrays , one with all the operators and one with all operands.

```
            String[] aa = op.split("[*+-]");
            for ( String s : aa )
                    System.out.println(s);
            String[] bb = op.split("[0-9]");
            for ( String s : bb )
                    System.out.println(s);

            // Now loop through the operand array and apply the necessary oeprator in order
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < aa.length ; i++ ) {
                      int val = applyOperator(Integer.parseInt(aa[i]), Integer.parseInt(aa[i+1]), bb[i]);
            }
```

This is pseudocode only .. I will leave you to implement the applyOperator method

Comment: ,how should i make it generic.i have no thoughts about it.Im new to Java as well.

Comment: find the index of the operator and substring to it.

Comment: How will the applyOperator method work ??please post the code logic

Comment: i have done with index of operator but its still not working.could you review my code

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `rightSide` has the String value "-" and you are attempting to do `Integer.parseInt()` on it.

Comment: any ideas on how to make it generic.Help provided will be helpful.

Comment: Since im new to java can you provide me with the fix to my code

Answer (score 0):

Your code for determining `rightSide` as well as the method `findOperatorLocation` both assume that all numbers and intermediary results have only one digit. So you run into problems as soon as you have an intermediarey result (16) that has two digits.

Comment: ,how do i handle for any digits.?COuld you please help me out

Comment: ,how should i make it generic.i have no thoughts about it.Im new to Java as well,any fix u could share

Comment: @user756993: instead of assuming a fixed position for the operator, use indexOf() to find the actual position of the first operator character in the string.

Comment: Since im new to Java,i have been struggling to get this done for a week now,if you can help me with the implementation,it will be helpful

Comment: ,requesting  you to provide the fix to my code.i m using indexOf in my code as well which is not working,i dont know how to proceed.

Comment: i m using indexOf in my code as well which is not working,i dont know how to proceed.Could you provide me with the generic fix.

Comment: @user756993: It has nothing to do with Java, but with basic understanding of what you're doing. You're using indexOf to find the index of the first occurence of the character at index 1. The result can't be anything other than 0 or 1. What you should do is use indexOf to find the first occurrence of a operation character (+-*/)

Comment: ,`What you should do is use indexOf to find the first occurrence of a operation character (+-*/)`--this is what i dont know how to accomplish,can you provide a fix for my code.

Comment: Hi Micheal.i have been struggling to get this rite for a long time now could you provide me with the code fix.

Comment: @user756993: `string.indexOf('-')` finds the index of the first minus sign. Do that for all the operators and the smallest of these indexes is the first operator. And no, I won't write your code for you.

Comment: im really new to java.....and finding this part difficult to implement @ Michael.Atleast this time you can help me out.

Comment: @user756993: no, I can't. You've been told how the problem can be solved in considerable detail. If you still can't follow the advice, then you very much deserve to fail whatever class this is for, as you've proven unable to learn what it's supposed to teach.

Comment: I have used indexOf in my new program,but it is not working. Where should i put my new program

Answer (score 0):

You have a small bug in your program where you correctly consider digits to be numbers, but you incorrectly consider all numbers to only consist of one digit.

Since a number only consists of one digit, when handling "16-5" the values are

```
left side = "1"
operator = "6"
right side = "-"
rest of string = "5"
```

If you improved your "left side" routine, then it would recogonize the entire left side as

```
left side = "16"
operator = "-"
right side = "5"
rest of string = empty or "", depending on how you code it
```

Keep in mind that if you have a bug on the "left side" detection where you assume that all numbers are one digit long, odds are good you have a bug on the "right side" detection where you assume that all numbers are one digit long.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you have an issue with `findOperatorLocation`, but let me attempt to reframe their suggestions using the pattern I see. Essentially what you are trying to build here is an interpreter for a programming language whose only statements are the mathematical operations you have defined.

Since you are building a programming language interpreter there are 3 steps that your `evaluate` method goes through 1) scanning & parsing 2) creation of intermediate code 3) execution. The issue in your program lies in the parsing step. If you were to exact the parsing functionality to a separate function, and run test strings through that function, then it would be easier for you to see what is going wrong. This is mostly a design problem; you are trying to verify all three steps (scanning/parsing, code generation, and execution) through the `evaluate` function. This results in a large surface area to debug.

If you are going to continue to evolve the statements that your program supports, I would recommend that you review some resources on parsing such as: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCslqgM48D4&ab_channel=NextDayVideo
Happy Coding!